# Lost update in Concurrency control?

Tags: concurrency

I have two transactions T and U which are executed simultaneously in a DB. How does one provide an example of the lost update problem?

We can assume that we have three accounts A,B,C and they each have £100,£200 and £300 respectively.

Comment: This was tagged as not-programming-related. It seems pretty programming related to me...

Comment: Well it's way too generalized - bordering on not a real question - please provide some more specifics - thanks.

Comment: it's a pretty specific problem with a general solution - although the question is obviously a homework or exam question

Answer (score 21):

The "lost update" problem relates to concurrent reads and updates to data, in a system where readers do not block writers. It is not necessary for the transactions to be exactly simultaneous.

1. Session #1 reads Account A, gets 100.
2. Session #2 reads Account A, gets 100.
3. Session #2 updates Account A to 150 (+50) and commits.
4. Session #1 updates Account A to 120 (+20) and commits.

In this scenario, because Session #1 does not know that another session has already modified the account, the update by Session #2 is overwritten ("lost").

There are several ways to solve this, e.g. version numbers or before-and-after compares.

Comment: By version numbers you mean using optimistic locking of hibernate

Comment: Hi Anand, yes, as far as I understand Hibernate's implementation of optimistic locking involves comparison of record version numbers. I'm not sure if that's the only method that Hibernate supports, however.

Answer (score 1):

(3) Update Account A to 150 Where Account is 100 -> Account A is now 150

(4) Update Account A to 120 Where Account is 100 -> Update fail because account A is 150 and not 100

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when two transactions that access the same database items have their operations interleaved in a way that makes the value of some database item incorrect.