# Multiple JPA repositories to same entity across different spring projects

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a pretty complex project that involves multiple services in the backend. Each service is its own spring project. I am using an H2 instance for the project.

For the sake of example, let's say I have the same entity class across all services, lets say `EntityA`. Is it possible to have multiple JPA repositories across all the projects for that `EntityA`?

In Service1:

```
public interface EntityARepository extends JpaRepository<EntityA, ID>
```

In Service2:

```
public interface EntityARepository extends JpaRepository<EntityA, ID>
```

etc...

Having something like that in each of the services, which are each their own spring project? I need to be able to access `EntityA` across all of the services but would like to only use one H2 instance.

Is this possible? I know that it is not possible to have multiple repositories for the same entity within one spring project. But how about across multiple?

Comment: Yes its possible indeed.

Comment: Note that what you're doing is called _integration through the database_ and is generally a dangerous design. (To your basic question, it's entirely _possible_ to have multiple repositories for the same entity; just distinguish them clearly by type at the point of use.)

Answer (score 0):

As it was already said in the comments: Yes you can do that as long as the repositories are in different projects.

If multiple projects actually write to the database you might want to ensure you don't get ["lost updates"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/880815/66686) by using [JPAs optimistic locking facility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661328/optimistic-locking-in-a-stateless-application-with-jpa-hibernate).